# Clicking on a drop down with Cypress

Tags: html, typescript, cypress

I'm new to Cypress and typescript and I need to select an item from a dropdown menu using cypress but I can't figure out how to do that. [Here is the link to the HTML code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CnZf6.jpg)

I've tried the following and it gave these error messages

```
cy
.select('#wcag-label')
.select('#af57032ed474-2')
.click();
```

The error message for that was "A child command must be chained after a parent because it operates on a previous subject."

So I tried:

```
cy
.get('#wcag-label')
.select('#af57032ed474-2')
.click();
```

With the error message `Timed out retrying: Expected to find element: #wcag-label, but never found it.`

I know I need to select the id of the object and then select which id I want to click on but I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: https://dev.to/jwp/cypress-and-material-select-56a1

Comment: It looks like you've just added the id incorrectly - you have `...role="listbox" wcag-label>`, but if you change it to `...role="listbox" id="wcag-label">` then Cypress will find it when you use `cy.get('#wcag-label')`.

Comment: @eric99 I don't think I have access to the source code is there any other way I can do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the error it looks like it never founds element with id "wcag-label", maybe you should first wait to be visible and then to select element from the drop down with text af57032ed474-2:

You don't need click after select:

```
cy.get('#wcag-label').should('be.visible');    
cy.get('#wcag-label').select('#af57032ed474-2');
```

Comment: So for clarification, is the .get for the id of the dropdown bar and the .select is the id of the element I want to choose?

Comment: @Sanika select the id of dropdown and then select the text of element you want to choose.